# How to get original object from Vue 3 proxy?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to get original object that was passed to `reactive()` from Vue 3 proxy. This is my code:

```
const token: any = reactive(new Token());
console.log(token.target);//prints undefined
```

Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: What do you need this for? This could be XY problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reactive` returns JavaScript `Proxy` which doesn't expose original object, unless a proxy is revokable.

Original object can be accessed through `__v_raw` property on reactive proxy, it's not a part of public API and shouldn't be relied on. Public API is `toRaw`:

```
const token = reactive(new Token());
const rawToken = toRaw(token);
```

If original object is needed then the reference can be kept:

```
const rawToken = new Token();
const token = reactive(rawToken);
```

But note this is discouraged in the official documentation:

> It is **not** recommended to hold a persistent reference to the original
> object. Use with caution.

[Reactivity API: Advanced](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw)

Comment: What about `ref` though?  This doesn't seem to work to get the underlying object of a `ref`.

Comment: Can you clarify what's your case? Are you trying to do `reactive(someRef)`?

Comment: I have a ref to an imported Vue component I don't know the type of: `const abcRef = ref(null); ... <template><v-foo></v-foo></template>`.  I want to know its underlying type so TS doesn't complain about that ref, which is currently `Ref<null>` because of that initiating null value, then I can define it as `Ref<underlyingtype | null>`.

Comment: It would be `ref<ComponentPublicInstance | null>(null)` for a random component. Is this what you want?